# Good resources on structuring asynchronous code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

One thing I keep running across is a stack of functions at the bottom of my code. I can mange it pretty well but I think their are probably better standards and practice out there that will help when sharing code.

I was hoping to see how other people structure their code, or some resources on good techniques for writing async JS.

Comment: Using a module like [Futures](http://coolaj86.info/futures/) should keep your code tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably learn the most by reviewing the source code for some of the more popular Node modules on GitHub. [Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) and [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) come to mind. You could even look at the [lib](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib) directory of Node itself.

Other than that, the best way to structure a 'stack' of functions that is starting to get overwhelming is to group the functions by purpose and place each group in its own module (and therefore, separate file).